# how to display the name field of Category model instead of [<Category: hockey>, <Category: run>]

Tags: python, django

what I'm trying to do is for sports category page display links to hockey and running category pages. I think I'm almost there, but instead of `[<Category: hockey>, <Category: run>]` I want hockey and run to be there.

```
class Category(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True) 
    parent_cat = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)
```

In template I have

```
<a href="/category/{{something}}">{{category.category_set.all}}</a>
```

my url

```
url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_url>[\w|\W]+)/$', views.category, name='category'),
```

can someone please help me out here?

Edit:My full model

```
class Category(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    parent_cat = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)
    hotCat = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    sponsored = models.ForeignKey(Sponsored, null=True, blank=True)


    objects = CategoryManager()

    def __unicode__(self): 
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/category/%s/" %self.name

    def get_image_url(self):
        return "%s%s" %(settings.MEDIA_URL, self.image)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `for in` loop in your template, to display the name for each category, try this :

```
{% for cat in category.category_set.all %}<a href="{{ cat.get_absolute_url }}">{{ cat.name }}</a> {% endfor %}
```

But I assumed that `category.category_set.all` was the way you get the set of categories to traverse. I'm not sure that this is the correct way to do this (if may be a way do to this I don't know though).

Why don't you get all categories from your view and passing the set directly as something like "categories" to your `render()` call?

With something like this :

```
def myview(request):
    cats = Category.objects.all()
    render(request, "mytemplate.html", {"categories" : cats})
```

Comment: I posted my full model, I think you misunderstood the question because of the way I put it

Comment: {{category.name}} will bring the category name of the page I'm in

Comment: @mikebraa I edited my answer, assuming that `category.category_set.all` will get you the set of categories to traverse.

Comment: thank you very much it shows the name but it takes me to the wrong url tho, it takes me to http://127.0.0.1:8000/category//category/hockey/ where it should be http://127.0.0.1:8000/category/hockey/...thanks for the solution

Comment: Just remove the `/category` in your template then. (cf. the answer I just edited)

Comment: yeah I already did that:) and to answer your question from your solution, I'm not getting all categories I'm getting the categories that are the children of patrent_category here